# How to create custom chart in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is it possible to create any kind of chart in azure boards?
I am trying to have this kind of chart:
I have a specific query that shows me 'cool' tasks:
[image: cool tasks query]

I want to make a statistic chart with the percentage of done cool tasks. For example (it is on excel)

[image]

I tried to make this chart on the dashboard, but I couldn't found this kind of chart. Is there any possibility to make this kind of chart?

Answer (score 0):

No, the built-in charts are quite limited. Your best option is to open the query results in Excel, and then create the table/chart you want in the Excel version.

[image]

A word of caution though. The data will be live and linked to TFS, so be careful you don't edit something and publish it back into TFS.